# PowerShell script that connect to BambooHR

Tags: powershell, api

I am trying to create a powershell script that connect to bamboohr and count number of active employees grouped by division at current time, at the start of the month, and at the end of the month and return result as table format.

For now I tried to get the number of employee at current and last month. I also tried to change it to the past 4 months but all the result are the same. I am really confuse how could I filter by the date.

It is first time for me to write script like this.

```
$headers=@{}
$headers.Add("Accept", "application/json")
$headers.Add("authorization", "Basic api=")
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/domain/v1/employees/directory' -Method GET -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing
Write-Output ""
Write-Output "-------------------------------Completed connecting to BambooHR----------------------------------"
Write-Output ""

# Get the start and end dates for last month
$start_of_last_month = Get-Date -Day 1 -Month (Get-Date).AddMonths(-4).Month
$end_of_last_month = $start_of_last_month.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)

#convert from json to hash table
$convert = $response.content | ConvertFrom-Json
$employees = $convert.employees 

$date = "2023,01,01"
# Group employees by division
$employeeGroups = $employees | Group-Object -Property division | Select-Object name, Count | Where-Object { $_.hireDate -le $date -and ($_.terminationDate -eq $null -or $_.terminationDate -ge $date) }

Write-Output "Employees by division 1:"
$employeeGroups | Format-Table -AutoSize 

Write-Output ""
Write-Output "-----------------------------------------------------------------"
Write-Output ""

$employment_status_metadata = $response.employmentStatus.options
$active_employment_status_id = ($employment_status_metadata | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "Active" }).id

# Filter the employees by active employment status and termination date for last month
$active_employees_last_month = $employees | Where-Object { $_.employmentStatus.id -eq $active_employment_status_id -and $_.hireDate -le $end_of_last_month -and ($_.terminationDate -eq $null -or $_.terminationDate -gt $start_of_last_month) }

# Group the active employees by division and count the number of employees in each division
$div_counts_last_month = $active_employees_last_month | Group-Object Division | Select-Object @{Name="Division";Expression={$_.Name}}, @{Name="Count";Expression={$_.Count}}

# Output the number of active employees by division for last month
Write-Output "Number of active employees by division for last month:"
$div_counts_last_month | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

**Result**: I've got a table with data is correct for the current number of user working or active users but not for past months.

[image]

Comment: You are treating date as a string instead of as a DateTime object [$date = "2023,01,01"}  Try following : $date = [DateTime]"1/1/2023".  You can't compare the string using -ge : $_.terminationDate -ge $date

Comment: And to filter the data be the date, where should I add the date? to the URL? I want number of employee on specific date.

Comment: The filtering by date depends on code and database that can vary.  There is no one answer I can give.